# Apache htacces redirects to 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have this link which i access:

```
 http://domain.com/search/csgo/US/nameorip/?matching=dust2
```

.htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([a-z_]+)/([A-Z_]+)/([a-z]+)/?matching=(.*)?$   servers.php?game=$1&location=$2&query_by=$3&matching=$4 [NC,L]
```

After i access this link, I'm redirected too 404 page. Why ? What is wrong with my `.htacces` File ?

EDIT: I read documentation and I think a problem is at `matching`, right ?

Comment: That is correct. You cannot check the query string inside the rewrite pattern. You need to check it using `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^matching=([^&])$ [NC]`.

Comment: My apologies, left the `+` out there - should be `[^&]+`, as in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^matching=([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^search/([a-z_]+)/([A-Z_]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ servers.php?game=$1&location=$2&query_by=$3&matching=%1 [NC,L]
```